# ServiceStack replacement for WCF

Tags: servicestack

I currently use a command-line client, that communicates WCF to communicate between a client (over http) and an IIS web server.  The WCF request packages is very large (like 10 GB).  Can I use service stack to communicate GB sized requests (which include a large compressed package of data as part of the request)?

Answer (score 1):

For very large files the most efficient way is to upload the file as a HTTP File Upload (i.e. multipart/form-data). If you instead want to send large API requests the most efficient format for binary data is either [Protocol Buffers](https://docs.servicestack.net/protobuf-format) or [Message Pack](https://docs.servicestack.net/messagepack-format).

But typically you'd be sending large data files via HTTP File Upload. ServiceStack doesn't impose any limits on the size of the upload itself so any restrictions would be imposed on the underlying HTTP Server. I'd recommend starting from one of the [.NET Core Project Templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/web-new) whose underlying Kestrel HTTP Server is more efficient than the ASP.NET or HttpListener HTTP Servers available in the .NET Framework.

There's a quick file upload example in [single and multiple file upload examples](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#uploading-files) docs:

#### Uploading Files

You can access uploaded files independently of the Request DTO using `Request.Files`. e.g:

```
public object Post(MyFileUpload request)
{
    if (this.Request.Files.Length > 0)
    {
        var uploadedFile = base.Request.Files[0];
        uploadedFile.SaveTo(MyUploadsDirPath.CombineWith(file.FileName));
    }
    return HttpResult.Redirect("/");
}
```

ServiceStack's [imgur.servicestack.net](http://imgur.servicestack.net) example shows how to access the [byte stream of multiple uploaded files](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Imgur/blob/master/src/Imgur/Global.asax.cs#L62), e.g:

```
public object Post(Upload request)
{
    foreach (var uploadedFile in base.Request.Files
       .Where(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            uploadedFile.WriteTo(ms);
            WriteImage(ms);
        }
    }
    return HttpResult.Redirect("/");
}
```

The `Request.Files` is the uploaded file collection provided by the underlying HTTP Server, i.e. ServiceStack doesn't buffer any of the contents itself.

You can upload HTTP Files using either [HTTP Utils PostFileToUrl() or UploadFile() APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils#uploading-files). ServiceStack's C# Service Clients also have a number of [File Upload APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#file-uploads) where you can send multiple file uploads as well as a populated Request DTO with multiple file uploads:

#### File Uploads

You can use the `PostFile` API to upload a single File, with the Route of the Service you want to call,
the name of the file and the `Stream` of its contents, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
using (var fileStream = new FileInfo(filePath).OpenRead())
{
    var fileName = "upload.html";
    var response = client.PostFile<FileUploadResponse>("/files/upload", 
        fileStream, fileName, MimeTypes.GetMimeType(fileName));
}
```

Files uploaded using the `PostFile*` APIs are uploaded as a HTTP POST using the `multipart/form-data` Content-Type which can 
be accessed from the `IRequest.Files` collection in your Services, e.g:

```
[Route("/files/upload")]
public class UploadFile {}

public class UploadFileService : Service
{
    readonly string UploadsDir = "uploads";

    public object Post(UploadFile request)
    {
        var uploadedFile = base.Request.Files[0];
        VirtualFiles.WriteFile(UploadsDir.CombineWith(uploadedFile.FileName), uploadedFile.InputStream);
        return new FileUploadResponse { ... };
    }
}
```

You can use the `PostFileWithRequest` API To also include additional metadata with your File Upload, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/files/upload")]
public class FileUpload : IReturn<FileUploadResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

var client = new JsonHttpClient(baseUrl);
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
using (var fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
{
    var request = new FileUpload {
        CustomerId = customerId,
        CreatedDate = fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc,
    };

    var response = client.PostFileWithRequest<FileUploadResponse>(
        "/files/upload", fileStream, fileInfo.Name, request);
}
```

#### Multiple File Uploads

The `PostFilesWithRequest` APIs available in all .NET Service Clients allow you to easily upload multiple 
streams within a single HTTP request. It supports populating Request DTO with any combination of QueryString 
and POST'ed FormData in addition to multiple file upload data streams:

```
using (var stream1 = uploadFile1.OpenRead())
using (var stream2 = uploadFile2.OpenRead())
{
    var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
    var response = client.PostFilesWithRequest<MultipleFileUploadResponse>(
        "/multi-fileuploads?CustomerId=123",
        new MultipleFileUpload { CustomerName = "Foo,Bar" },
        new[] {
            new UploadFile("upload1.png", stream1),
            new UploadFile("upload2.png", stream2),
        });
}
```

Example using only a Typed Request DTO. The `JsonHttpClient` also includes async equivalents for each of the 
`PostFilesWithRequest` APIs:

```
using (var stream1 = uploadFile1.OpenRead())
using (var stream2 = uploadFile2.OpenRead())
{
    var client = new JsonHttpClient(baseUrl);
    var response = await client.PostFilesWithRequestAsync<MultipleFileUploadResponse>(
        new MultipleFileUpload { CustomerId = 123, CustomerName = "Foo,Bar" },
        new[] {
            new UploadFile("upload1.png", stream1),
            new UploadFile("upload2.png", stream2),
        });
}
```